# Inno Setup Uninstall

Tags: uninstallation

This is my situation, something like this:
I have three files: file1.txt, file2.txt, and file3.exe

1. I want to put three of them into a Directory in C:\Program Files, run file3.exe and create an uninstaller to uninstall everything with double-click on it.
2. when I make a double-click on uninstaller, the file3.exe will be uninstalled and all files will be removed from that Directory.

I've just done the first step, how can I do to get second step?
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31454/How-To-Make-Your-Application-Delete-Itself-Immedia)

or I used this one: create an exe that can create a batch file which will uninstall the app and delete itself

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code snippet of inno setup ,

```
[Files]
Source: "file3.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "file1.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "file2.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\file3.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&',   '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```